# Parsing XML and getting a URL value to download a file

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, download

I am using a tutorial about a listview [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) which get some information like the names of the artist... and the URL for the image of artist and making a listview.

```
    <music>
    <song>
    <id>1</id>
    <title>Someone Like You</title>
    <artist>Adele</artist>
    <duration>4:47</duration>
    <thumb_url>http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/adele.png</thumb_url>
    </song>
    <song>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>Space Bound</title>
    <artist>Eminem</artist>
    <duration>4:38</duration>
    <thumb_url>
    http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/eminem.png
    </thumb_url>
    </song>
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to add another node called mp3 and give the song's URL to each array in the XML so that by clicking each row of the list the proper mp3 file be downloaded. Like below:

```
<music>
<song>
<id>1</id>
<title>Someone Like You</title>
<artist>Adele</artist>
<duration>4:47</duration>
<thumb_url>http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/adele.png</thumb_url>
**<mp3> some URL1 </mp3>**
</song>
<song>
<id>2</id>
<title>Space Bound</title>
<artist>Eminem</artist>
<duration>4:38</duration>
<thumb_url>http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/eminem.png</thumb_url>
**<mp3> some URL2 </mp3>**
</song>
.
.
.
```

I changed the main java code like below but I can just download the "file_url" (new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(**file_url**);) string which is defined as direct URL entered before. Please help me to get the mp3 URL from xml for download.

```
    public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

  // Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
  // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;
  // File url to download
private static String file_url = "the URL of the file that I don't want to use this method for downloading the file";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
    }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);





    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(file_url);



        }
    }); 

}   
/**
 * Showing Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type:
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to download file
 * */
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread
     * Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new  FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Downloadmanager.zip");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
   }

    /**
     * After completing background task
     * Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);


    }

}
```

}

Comment: hi, i didn't get correctly. how you get xml? from server? after that you want to add <mp3> tag?

Comment: this tutorial may help you although its old: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/